# Adding a horizontal line in canvasJS

Tags: javascript, html, canvasjs

I am making a comfort level chart with multiple area charts. I want to draw a horizontal line, making it a level line. I am getting the area charts data. but i cannot get line data. I have to create it by own. 
Please help.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can add Custom Horizontal Lines by using [StripLine with value](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisy/strip-lines/value/)